# Convert Array value to Int in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to convert Convert Array value to Int in Laravel. ( Array have single value using Min and Max function)

Now need to convert both value into INT and use them in ChartJS.....

or is there any other option to use the same for Y Axis Scale....

```
    Min Value from Array----
     array:1 [▼
     "amount" => 55
    ]

    Max Value from Array----
    array:1 [▼
    "amount" => 3249
    ]
```

Comment: In general, you can cast a value as integer like so: `$x = (int) $x;`  Think we need more context of where/how you are using it within Laravel, if Laravel is making it a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just put values into  in your blade file? Something like:

```
<script> 
const jsObject: {
property: {{ $min['amount'] }}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks.... Working

Comment: Please mark my answer as helpful :)